# fail to simulate play api Request

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have a class that have that receives `Option[Request[_]]` as an implicit (play.api.mvc.Request):

```
class MyClass @Inject()(...)(implicit val request: Option[Request[_]]) { ...
```

my problem is in my test im using play.api.test.inject like:

```
  val myClass: MyClass = inject[MyClass]
```

and to be able to do that in my test i have to bring this Request implicit. so the way i did was with `mockito.ArgumentMatchers` like this:

```
  implicit val origReq: Option[Request[_]] = any[Option[Request[_]]]
```

but when i run the test i get this error:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for scala.Option<play.api.mvc.Request<?>> was bound.
  while locating scala.Option<play.api.mvc.Request<?>>
    for the 3rd parameter of streams.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.scala:16)
  while locating streams.MyClass

1 error 
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for scala.Option<play.api.mvc.Request<?>> was bound.
  while locating scala.Option<play.api.mvc.Request<?>>
    for the 3rd parameter of streams.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.scala:16)
  while locating streams.MyClass
```

what am i doing wrong? :/

Comment: maybe `Option[any[Request[_]]]`???

Comment: @MikhailIonkin tried ```implicit val origReq: Option[Request[_]] = Some(ArgumentMatchers.any[Request[_]])``` still dosent work unfortunately

Comment: the same exception?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin yes, drives me nuts..

Comment: Can you got val *without* Option? and after you can create implicit val that will wrap it. I think that problem is that mokito can't has Option's implementation of all types

Comment: t@MikhailIonkin tried to print ```val req = ArgumentMatchers.any[Request[_]]``` and its null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196223/discussion-between-mikhail-ionkin-and-jack-miao).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining a class that's supposed to be instantiated by guice which requires an optional request, it is very likely that you need this request to be actually request-scoped (a different object in on each request) which isn't straightforward in play.

I don't know how `inject[MyClass]` behaves, I guess that it won't look for the implicit optional request on the scope but it will try to instantiate `MyClass` using the available modules (Just In Time bindings aren't enough because `Request[_]` is not concrete, you could get the tests passing by defining a specific binding for your test but it won't be that easy to get the app working), in any case, providing objects with generic types is not that simple, because there are many possible implementations for a single `Request[_]`, think about replacing `_` by `Int`, `String`, etc.

A good idea would be to refactor `MyClass` to require the implicit request on each method instead, which resolves the problematic provisioning.

If you still want to go with the implicit request on the constructor, you'll need to look into request-scoped bindings on play, which is a topic by itself.